# HTTP4 component is ignoring my protocol, hostname and port numbber

Tags: apache-camel

I am trying to call an https service. The URL is 
https4://httpbin.org/get?connectTimeout=800
but it is trying to connect to
http://localhost:8080/api/v1/raw?connectTimeout=800

```
        restConfiguration()
                .component("restlet").port(8080)
                .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.off)
                .apiContextPath("api-doc")
                .apiProperty("api.title", "Unified Item API")
                .apiProperty("api.version", "v1");

        rest().path("/api/v1/raw")
                .get().to("direct:agg");

        from("direct:agg")
                .validate(authorizationPredicate)
                .to("https4://httpbin.org/get?connectTimeout=800");
```

This is the relevant portion of the log:

```
12:56:12.522 [Restlet-1916062307] DEBUG o.a.camel.processor.SendProcessor - >>>> direct://agg Exchange[ID-C02VNC5EHTD5MBP-1569603368539-0-2]
12:56:12.736 [Restlet-1916062307] DEBUG o.a.c.p.v.PredicateValidatingProcessor - Validation succeed for Exchange[ID-C02VNC5EHTD5MBP-1569603368539-0-2] with Predicate[com.homedepot.merch.unifiedItemApi.predicates.AuthorizationPredicate@198c8572]
12:56:12.737 [Restlet-1916062307] DEBUG o.a.camel.processor.SendProcessor - >>>> https4://httpbin.org/get?connectTimeout=800 Exchange[ID-C02VNC5EHTD5MBP-1569603368539-0-2]
12:56:12.747 [Restlet-1916062307] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.apache.camel.component.jackson.converter.JacksonTypeConverters'
12:56:12.757 [Restlet-1916062307] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.apache.camel.component.jackson.converter.JacksonTypeConverters'
12:56:12.759 [Restlet-1916062307] DEBUG o.a.c.component.http4.HttpProducer - Executing http GET method: http://localhost:8080/api/v1/raw?connectTimeout=800
12:56:12.773 [Restlet-1916062307] DEBUG o.a.h.c.protocol.RequestAddCookies - CookieSpec selected: default
12:56:12.780 [Restlet-1916062307] DEBUG o.a.h.c.protocol.RequestAuthCache - Auth cache not set in the context
12:56:12.781 [Restlet-1916062307] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.BasicHttpClientConnectionManager - Get connection for route {}->http://localhost:8080
12:56:12.790 [Restlet-1916062307] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection - http-outgoing-0: set socket timeout to 0
12:56:12.791 [Restlet-1916062307] DEBUG o.a.h.impl.execchain.MainClientExec - Opening connection {}->http://localhost:8080
12:56:12.792 [Restlet-1916062307] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection - http-outgoing-0: Shutdown connection
12:56:12.792 [Restlet-1916062307] DEBUG o.a.h.impl.execchain.MainClientExec - Connection discarded
12:56:12.792 [Restlet-1916062307] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.BasicHttpClientConnectionManager - Releasing connection [Not bound]
12:56:12.793 [Restlet-1916062307] INFO  o.a.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec - I/O exception (org.apache.http.conn.UnsupportedSchemeException) caught when processing request to {}->http://localhost:8080: http protocol is not supported
12:56:12.794 [Restlet-1916062307] DEBUG o.a.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec - http protocol is not supported
org.apache.http.conn.UnsupportedSchemeException: http protocol is not supported
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:109)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.BasicHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(BasicHttpClientConnectionManager.java:325)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:381)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at org.apache.camel.component.http4.HttpProducer.executeMethod(HttpProducer.java:334)
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the REST consumer sets the header Exchange.HTTP_URI to the URL it received. The HTTP4 producer uses this header to override what is in the URL it is given. The solution was to remove the header like this:

```
           from("direct:agg")
                    .validate(authorizationPredicate)
                    .removeHeader("Exchange.HTTP_URI")
```

Comment: Are you sure this works? I would expect `removeHeader(Exchange.HTTP_URI)` or `removeHeader("CamelHttpUri")` instead of `removeHeader("Exchange.HTTP_URI")`. And better remove all http-component related headers, to avoid another collisions in future (eg. for http method). `.removeHeaders("CamelHttp*")`

Comment: Yes it works. I did not post that it did work until I'd tried it. The documentation for the HTTP and HTTP4 components document this behavior.

Comment: What @Bedla meant is that he (and I too) has doubts that it works with the Java constant and quotes. I would guess that Camel tries to remove a Header that is called `Exchange.HTTP_URI`, but the header is named `CamelHttpUri`. Therefore either you use the Java constant without quotes or you use the real name with quotes. I don't think (as @Bedla) that it works if you put the Java constant in quotes.